# Material-UI: How to bring the Drawer component below the AppBar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am playing around with the Material UI drawer component, I want the drawer to below appbar, where I want to toggle the onclick of the hamburger icon to open and close, when I click the hamburger icon it should open the drawer below and onclick of it again it should also close, and I don't want hamburger icon to move onclick of it, it should be static in one place.it shouldn't move, only the drawer should open and move.how can I achieve it in material ui
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ehs05?file=/demo.js:0-6433

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth,
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
  },
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open,
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Persistent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open,
        })}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
          ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum
          facilisis leo vel. Risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit
          gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id
          donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit
          adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras.
          Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Mauris commodo quis
          imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. At augue eget
          arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem
          donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla
          facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac
          tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat
          consequat mauris. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed
          vulputate odio. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. In
          hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et
          tortor. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin
          nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Commodo viverra maecenas
          accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.
        </Typography>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want the drawer to below appbar

To put the `Drawer` below the `AppBar`, add the following line in your `AppBar` style:

```js
appBar: {
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1, // add this line to increate appBar z-index
},
```

> it should be static in one place.it shouldn't move

If you don't want the `AppBar` moved when the `Drawer` is opened, remove`appBarShift` style. Change:

```js
<AppBar
  position="fixed"
  className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
    [classes.appBarShift]: open,
  })}
>
```

To:

```js
<AppBar
  position="fixed"
  className={classes.appBar}
>
```

> and I don't want hamburger icon to move onclick of it

Similarly, remove the style that make the `IconButton` hidden when the `Drawer` is opened

```js
<IconButton className={classes.menuButton} {...props} />
```

> when I click the hamburger icon it should open the drawer below and onclick of it again it should also close

Replace the `handleDrawerOpen` with your handler that toggles the `Drawer` instead

```js
const handleToggleDrawer = () => {
  setOpen((o) => !o);
};
```

```js
<IconButton
  color="inherit"
  aria-label="open drawer"
  onClick={handleToggleDrawer}
  edge="start"
  className={classes.menuButton}
>
  <MenuIcon />
</IconButton>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66898908/how-to-bring-drawer-component-of-material-ui-below-appbar]